# How can I force firefox to buffer full video content

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, html, video

Firefox intentionally doesn't always autobuffer / preload a web video's full data. Their thinking is that it may not even be played. Unfortunately, this screws up my app.

How can I force the full video content to download in forefox, as it does in chrome? I need the event to occur, and I need to detect it without a false-positive.

Comment: Is that really firefox? I thought loading is controlled by website and it's player.

Comment: @Sergey — The website's player? The tags very strongly suggest that the player being used is Firefox via `<video>`.

Comment: Yeah, I am refering to <video>. This link would suggest that the full video is downloaded with preload="auto" unless the cache is full: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/video_preload_attribute/ . Call me crazy, but I'm not sure that this is what happens. Anyone else got a sanity check?

Comment: Noticed this same thing on chrome...actually noticed that if the video was cached sometimes the the progress event didn't fire. Talk about screwing up an app.